# Calculate Transition Matrix (Markov) in R

Tags: r, markov-process

Is there a way in R (a built-in function) to calculate the transition matrix for a Markov Chain from a set of observations?

For example, taking a data set like the following and calculate the first order transition matrix?

```
dat<-data.frame(replicate(20,sample(c("A", "B", "C","D"), size = 100, replace=TRUE)))
```

Comment: What is this matrix supposed to represent? One run of the Markov chain for each row (or column)? Or...?

Comment: This being 100 samples of state sequences (20 of them).

Comment: Are you looking for probability estimates or just counts?

Comment: Probability estimates. Using the observed sequences, what is the transition probability matrix (4x4 in this example).

Comment: You are looking for the Baum-Welch algorithm implemented in R. The first link in a simple google search produced the [answer](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/HMM/versions/1.0/topics/baumWelch). You might find a better implementation in the following links...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

*I am not immediately aware of a "built-in" function (e.g., in `base` or similar), but we can do this very easily and efficiently in a couple of lines of code.*

Here is a function that takes a **matrix** (not a data frame) as an input and produces either the transition counts (`prob=FALSE`) or, **by default** (`prob=TRUE`), the estimated transition probabilities.

```
# Function to calculate first-order Markov transition matrix.
# Each *row* corresponds to a single run of the Markov chain
trans.matrix <- function(X, prob=T)
{
    tt <- table( c(X[,-ncol(X)]), c(X[,-1]) )
    if(prob) tt <- tt / rowSums(tt)
    tt
}
```

If you need to call it on a data frame you can always do

```
trans.matrix(as.matrix(dat))
```

If you're looking for some third-party package, then [Rseek](http://www.rseek.org/) or the [R search site](http://www.r-project.org/search.html) may provide additional resources.

Comment: +1 There are also several R packages, including `HMM` and `RHMM` that might be helpful.

Comment: @Wayne: (+1) I have found the various HMM packages available in `R` to be *very* finicky in the past, particularly when it comes to fitting and I never found one I truly liked or trusted. Maybe the situation is better now. I would imagine they would get this right, though. If you know of such a solution, please submit it as an answer; I would be happy to up vote it!

Comment: I tried, but with no success. This problem doesn't involve hidden states and the packages I found don't have any utility functions that would do anything less than full-blown HMM. (As a side note, the `dat` data frame that the OP gives as an example has columns of data, and do they want a transition matrix per column, or an overall transition matrix or can we just turn the matrix into a vector?)

Comment: @Wayne: (+1) You raise a good point. I have *assumed* that each row is an *independent* run of the Markov chain and so we are seeking the transition probability estimates form these chains run in parallel. But, even if this were a chain that, say, wrapped from one end of a row down to the beginning of the next, the estimates would still be quite closer due to the Markov structure.

Comment: My intent was to treat each row of dat as a customer (for example) and the columns are their status at each of 20 periods. So AABB.... refers to customer 1 having status of A at time 1, A at time 2, B at time 3 etc. Does that align with what you expected with the code? And does that make sense to look at the longitudinal data with a transition matrix?

Comment: @B_Miner: Yes, it does, as long as you can reasonably assume that each customer behaves independently of all others. Such models and many extensions are relatively common in analyzing user behavior, e.g., on repeated visits to a website, etc.

Comment: If you have any examples of the use for customers (website visits for example) I would love the references. Also, does there need to be even lengths (here was 20 for every customer) of occurrences? I can certainly imagine that some customers have 2,3....20.

Comment: @cardinal: should not the correct answer be: trans.matrix <- function(X, prob=T){ tt <- table( X[ ,-ncol(X)], X[,-1] ); if(prob) ptt <- prop.table(tt); ptt }

Answer (score 38):

I have just uploaded a new R package, `markovchain`, based on S4 programming style. Along with various methods to handle S4 markovchain objects it contains a function to fit a Markov chain from a sequence of states. Have a look at:

```
library(markovchain) 
sequence <- c("a", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", 
              "b", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "a")
mcFit <- markovchainFit(data=sequence)
```

It could help.

Comment: A very nice package! Will you be supporting higher-order Markov Chains?

Comment: I have been asked for higher order Markov chain and another guy is writing some code. If you wish to partecipate in code developing send an email to mantainer address and we can discuss...

Comment: Hi, what’s the difference between markovchainFit and the function posted above? Do they yield the same results? Thanks

Comment: @aaaaa, the $markovchainFit$ function should be faster since build in Rcpp and compiled within a package. Also it handles much more data formats.