# Estimating Markov transition probabilities from sequence data

Tags: r, matlab, markov-process

I have a full set of sequences (432 observations to be precise) of 4 states $A-D$: eg

$$Y=\left(\begin{array}{c c c c c c c}
A& C& D&D  & B & A &C\\
B& A& A&C & A&- &-\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
B& C& A&D & A & B & A\\
    \end{array}\right)$$

**EDIT**:  The observation sequences are of unequal lengths! Does this change anything?

Is there a way of calculating the transition matrix $$P_{ij}(Y_{t}=j|Y_{t-1}=i)$$ in Matlab or R or similar?  I think the HMM package might help.  Any thoughts?

eg: [Estimating Markov chain probabilities](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14360/estimating-markov-chain-probabilities)

Comment: You have $4$ states: $S=\{1:=A,2:=B,3:=C,4:=D\}$. Let $n_{ij}$ be the number of times the chain made a transition from state $i$ to state $j$, for $ij,=1,2,3,4$. Compute the $n_{ij}$'s from your sample and estimate the transition matrix $(p_{ij})$ by maximum likelihood using the estimates $\hat{p}_{ij}=n_{ij}/\sum_{j=1}^4 n_{ij}$.

Comment: These notes derive the MLE estimates: http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/462/lectures/06/markov-mle.pdf

Comment: Similar question:http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26722/calculate-transition-matrix-markov-in-r

Comment: @B_Miner could you write your code in pseudo-code form for me? Or explain it in lay terms...  However I see it works in my R console.

Comment: I have a question: I understand your implementation and it lokks fine to me, but i was wondering why can't i simply use the Matlab hmmestimate function to compute the T matrix? Something like: states=[1,2,3,4]
[T,E]= hmmestimate ( x, states); where T is the transition matrix i'm interested in. I'm new to Markov chains and HMM so I'd like to understand the difference between the two implementations (if there is any).

Comment: I have a time series of dry, wet and neutral conditions for 4 seasons during 60 years (240 conditions). My data has text file format with 3 columns (year, season and rainfall conditions). How can I do markov chain by R. I want to calculate the transition probability matrix for the concurrency of wet, dry and neutral spells.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Please, check the comments above. Here is a quick implementation in R.

```
x <- c(1,2,1,1,3,4,4,1,2,4,1,4,3,4,4,4,3,1,3,2,3,3,3,4,2,2,3)
p <- matrix(nrow = 4, ncol = 4, 0)
for (t in 1:(length(x) - 1)) p[x[t], x[t + 1]] <- p[x[t], x[t + 1]] + 1
for (i in 1:4) p[i, ] <- p[i, ] / sum(p[i, ])
```

Results:

```
> p
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
[1,] 0.1666667 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.1666667
[2,] 0.2000000 0.2000000 0.4000000 0.2000000
[3,] 0.1428571 0.1428571 0.2857143 0.4285714
[4,] 0.2500000 0.1250000 0.2500000 0.3750000
```

A (probably dumb) implementation in MATLAB (which I have never used, so I don't know if this is going to work. I've just googled "declare vector matrix MATLAB" to get the syntax):

```
x = [ 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3 ]
n = length(x) - 1
p = zeros(4,4)
for t = 1:n
  p(x(t), x(t + 1)) = p(x(t), x(t + 1)) + 1
end
for i = 1:4
  p(i, :) = p(i, :) / sum(p(i, :))
end
```

Comment: Looks great! I'm not sure what the 3rd line does in your code though (mainly because I'm familiar with Matlab). Any chance you could write it in matlab or pseudo-code?  I'd be much obliged.

Comment: The third line does this: the chain values are $x_1,\dots,x_n$. For $t=1,\dots,n-1$, increment $p_{x_t,x_{t+1}}$.

Comment: The fourth line normalizes each line of the matrix $(p_{ij})$.

Comment: Bare with my slowness here. I do appreciate the MATLAB code translation although I still can't see what it's attempting to do in your first `for` loop. The 3rd line from the original code is counting the number of times $x$ goes from state $x_i$ to state $x_j$? If you could say it in words I'd appreciate that a lot. Cheers

Comment: I have implemented your R code and it works just as you explained. Which is great!  My query is now with regards to the $x$ vector... My observation sequences are of uneven lengths.  Eg the matrix I provided above. How would I change your code to handle this?

Comment: A realization of the chain is something like $1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 3, 1$. By inspection, it jumped from $1$ to $1$ one time, from $1$ to $2$ three times, and so on. What exactly you don't understand?

Comment: Can you clarify for me that your vector x is the same as concatenating my matrix rows? Ie one long sequence instead of many short ones?

Comment: No, $x$ is just one row. Don't concatenate because you will introduce "false" transitions: last state of one line $\to$ first state of the next line. You have to change the code to loop through the lines of your matrix and count the transitions. At the end, normalize each line of the transition matrix.

Comment: I'd really appreciate it if you could comment on whether you think it is possible to create a confidence interval for the transition probabilities?

Comment: @Zen Suppose instead of finding state transition matrix for 1 history step I wish to calculate for 2 history step.
P(State1|(State1, State2)): Probability of getting state1 given t-1 was state1 and t-2 was state2. How do I calculate these probabilities?

Comment: If it is a Markov chain, then $P(1\mid 1,2)=P(1\mid 2)$. So, there is nothing new. If it is not a Markov chain, keep a record of the $n^3$ triple of three consecutive transitions, simulate the process and compute the fraction of each triple.

Answer (score 11):

Here is my implementation in R

```
x <- c(1,2,1,1,3,4,4,1,2,4,1,4,3,4,4,4,3,1,3,2,3,3,3,4,2,2,3)
xChar<-as.character(x)
library(markovchain)
mcX<-markovchainFit(xChar)$estimate
mcX
```

Comment: [user32041](http://stats.stackexchange.com/users/32041/user32041)'s request (posted as an edit instead of a comment since he/she lacks reputation): How can I coerce the transitionMatrix of the markovchainFit result to a data.frame?

Comment: You can convert to $data.frame$ using $as(mcX,"data.frame")$

Comment: @GiorgioSpedicato can you comment on how to deal with sequences of unequal lengths (I cannot concatenate) please in your package?

Comment: @HCAI, please see the current vignette page 35-36

Comment: @GiorgioSpedicato thank you for the reference https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/markovchain/vignettes/an_introduction_to_markovchain_package.pdf. I still have n transition matrices, one for each sequence. What I’m after is one general one that takes into account all the sequence observations. Is there something I’m missing?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do it in Matlab:

```
x = [1,2,1,1,3,4,4,1,2,4,1,4,3,4,4,4,3,1,3,2,3,3,3,4,2,2,3];
counts_mat = full(sparse(x(1:end-1),x(2:end),1));
trans_mat = bsxfun(@rdivide,counts_mat,sum(counts_mat,2))
```

Acknowledgement owed to SomptingGuy: http://www.eng-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=236532