# How to test if "previous state" has influence on "subsequent state" in R

Tags: r, time-series, hypothesis-testing, stochastic-processes

Imagine a situation:
We have historical records (20 years) of three mines. **Does the presence of silver increases the probability of finding gold in next year?** How to test such question?

---

[image]

Here is example data:

```
mine_A <- c("silver","rock","gold","gold","gold","gold","gold",
            "rock","rock","rock","rock","silver","rock","rock",
            "rock","rock","rock","silver","rock","rock")
mine_B <- c("rock","rock","rock","rock","silver","rock","rock",
            "silver","gold","gold","gold","gold","gold","rock",
            "silver","rock","rock","rock","rock","rock")
mine_C <- c("rock","rock","silver","rock","rock","rock","rock",
            "rock","silver","rock","rock","rock","rock","silver",
            "gold","gold","gold","gold","gold","gold")
time <- seq(from = 1, to = 20, by = 1)
```

---

Comment: You may be interested in calculating [transition matrices](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26722/calculate-transition-matrix-markov-in-r).

Comment: Hi @AndyW! Thank you for comment. I am familiar with transition matrices package:makkovchain - markovchainFit(). May I use the probability values from transition matrix as p-values? Is there any way how to test hypothesis: "There exist a "silver-gold" relationship." (p-value = xx)?

Comment: @LadislavNado transition probabilities cannot be interpreted as p-values (they do not tell you anything about rejecting any H0), see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31/what-is-the-meaning-of-p-values-and-t-values-in-statistical-tests for learning more on p-values.

Comment: Thank you @Tim for your comment. You confirmed my doubts.

Comment: You are probably looking for [Anderson & Goodman (1957)](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177707039).

Comment: I see a problem with the way you have extracted your data. Consider your "silver: no" & "gold: yes" scenario, you should also be counting your consecutive runs of "gold" since that meets the logic criteria.

Comment: With the one cell corrected from 1 to 14, the model changes to:
Coefficients:
                    Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)          -1.2528     0.8018  -1.562    0.118
as.factor(c(0, 1))1   0.3655     0.8624   0.424    0.672

Comment: Thank you @leonardo. Your comment was crucial for obtaining a valid result.

Comment: This is a great question, but it's giving me nightmare flashbacks to my stochastic processes class in college.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**My best try:**
...usage of transition matrices suggested by @AndyW is probably not the solution I am looking for (based on @Tim's comment). So I've tried a different approach.
I found this [link](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat504/node/225) which deals with **how to do logistic regression where response variable y and a predictor variable x are both binary**.

According to example I should create 2 × 2 table based on my data:

```
               gold (yes)  gold (no)
silver (yes)       2           7
silver (no)       14          34
```

**How I extracted the values:**
[image]

And construct a model:

```
response <- cbind(yes = c(2, 14), no = c(7, 34))

mine.logistic <- glm(response ~ as.factor(c(0,1)),
                      family = binomial(link=logit))

summary(mine.logistic)
# Coefficients:
#                     Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
# (Intercept)          -1.2528     0.8018  -1.562    0.118
# as.factor(c(0, 1))1   0.3655     0.8624   0.424    0.672
```

Is it a good solution? **Does the p-value (0.673) mean that presence of silver no not increase the probability of finding gold?**

Comment: How did you generate these nice charts? Tikz?

Comment: Hi @ssdecontrol! Charts were made by hand in Inkscape.

Comment: Yes, that's a decent interpretation. Also, if you just look at the rows of your 2x2 table, on the top row (silver: yes) you have 9 cases, 2 of which had gold, so given silver probability of gold next year is 2/9 = 0.222. On the bottom row (silver: no) you have 48 cases, 14 of which had gold next year, so given no silver probability of gold is 14/(14+34) = 0.292. Given all that, it looks like silver *hurts* your chance of finding gold, though from your p-values not "statistically significantly".

Comment: Also be mindful of your coding, you start with `yes = c(2, 14), no = c(7, 34)`, which means your putting Silver:yes first. So when you do `as.factor(c(0, 1))` the 0 corresponds to silver: yes, which is your reference level and thus your intercept. The 0.67 p-value corresponds to the small positive bump you get in probability of finding gold moving from silver:yes to silver:no.

Comment: One last comment: you *are* using transition matrices. Your 2, 7, 14, 34 matrix is a transition matrix.