# How to chek if time spent in subsequent state has an influence of time spent in a present state?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, generalized-additive-model

As in the title of topic I'd like to check this assumption. I have already read the topic:

[How to test if "previous state" has influence on "subsequent state" in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148495/how-to-test-if-previous-state-has-influence-on-subsequent-state-in-r)

but it regards to categorical variable.

So let's say I have record of time spent in state 1 and its consecutive state 2. Moreover the the subject will not always move to state 2, hence I have more records for state 1.

Should I go for testing correlation significance? What if the data would perform nonlinearity, GAMs would be useful? But as in my proposition below I think it will only regard to magnitude of the effect while moving between states.

```
Data example:
ID State Time
1  S_1   10
1  S_2   30
2  S_1   15
3  S_1   59
3  S_2   65
4  S_1   20

model <- mgcv::gam(time ~ as.factor(state), data=data)
```

My best idea is to subset the data that has only those two states and test it so I can use subsequent state as the dependet variable.

```
Data example:
ID State Time
1  S_1   10
1  S_2   30
3  S_1   59
3  S_2   65

model <- mgcv::gam(S_1_time ~ s(S_2_time), data=data)
```

Is that a valid approach? How should I tackle the diagnostic of the model then?