# Markov chains: how to validate a state-transition probability matrix on new data?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, markov-process

I have the state - transition data with multiple sequences of unequal lengths, each sequence corresponding to one subject/person:

```
head(prob_tbl2)

   period1 period2 period3 period4 period5 period6 period7 period8
1    <NA>  active  active  active  active  active  active  active
2  active  active  active  active  active  active  active  active
3  active  active  active  active  active  active  active  active
4    <NA>    <NA>  active lapsed1  active lapsed1  active lapsed1
5    <NA>    <NA>  active lapsed1 lapsed2 lapsed3 lapsed4 lapsed5
6    <NA>  active lapsed1 lapsed2 lapsed3 lapsed4 lapsed5 lapsed6
```

Based on this data, I created a probability matrix (as suggested [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26722/calculate-transition-matrix-markov-in-r)):

```
trans.matrix <- function(X, prob=T)
{
  tt <- table( c(X[,-ncol(X)]), c(X[,-1]) )
  if(prob) tt <- tt / rowSums(tt)
  tt
}

prob_table= trans.matrix(as.matrix(prob_tbl2))
prob_table

           active    lapsed1    lapsed2    lapsed3    lapsed4    lapsed5    lapsed6    lapsed7
  active  0.56006735 0.43993265 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
  lapsed1 0.19183552 0.00000000 0.80816448 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
  lapsed2 0.10206773 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.89793227 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
  lapsed3 0.06437215 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.93562785 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000
  lapsed4 0.04468764 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.95531236 0.00000000 0.00000000
  lapsed5 0.04115773 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.95884227 0.00000000
  lapsed6 0.02306733 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.97693267
```

What is the way I could validate those probabilities, e.g. receive stadard errors/confidence intervals and cross-validate them against a new/unseen dataset? Could I bootstrap my data or apply MLE to get the uncertainty levels, if so, how to do it in R?

I tried to use `library(markovchain)`, with no much luck with my dataset, I described the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494690/markovchain-in-r-fitting-a-markovchain-to-mutliple-state-sequences)

Clearly, I'm new to Markov chains so any hints will be helpful!

Comment: How to do statistical/mathematical operations (with no suggested algorithm) are really not well-described  programming tasks. At best it would be a "urgent: do my coding for me" or a "please, find a package for me" question, both recognized as off-topic-for-SO. Get your theory straight before posting.

Comment: I am NOT expecting anyone to 'do my coding for me', I'm actually trying to understand the problem and appropriate methodologies and hope that someone could point me in the right direction. I updated my post by attempts I already made. If you want to help community here, you could start by giving up on not-so-productive comments like the one above

Comment: I think this question is better suited to cross validated as it is a method question not a coding one.

Comment: If you are trying to predict t steps ahead, can't you create a training and test set and then see how accurately the output transition matrix matches the true total counts of the observed states?

Comment: @JonnoBourne: that's exactly what I'm trying to do, but I'd expect to have a known uncertainty level to the probability estimates, e.g. standard errors to see whether the test set results are within training set's confidence intervals. To obtained these, I tried to use the `library(markovchain)` but it seems to work only for the sequence data (see the details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494690/markovchain-in-r-fitting-a-markovchain-to-mutliple-state-sequences) )

Comment: Is it the case that multiple transitions occur in each period, e.g one transition per person? or is there only a single transition in the period?

Comment: Only one transition is allowed per period, but each row is a person tracked over multiple periods. This means that there are multiple transitions per person, one per period

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A general approach is to look at [likelihood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function) of data given model parameters, i.e. $P(\text{sequences}|\text{matrix elements})$, or, for practical reasons, log-likelihood. For (not-hidden) Markov model, it is simply $\log L = \sum \log m_{ij}$, where we sum over all transitions that have occurred.

As you see, it does not matter what is the number of sequences, or their lengths (they may be all different). Be warned that a single occurrence of a transition with the matrix element being 0 makes likelihood zero.

In general, you compare it against baselines of uniformly distributed symbols, and symbols distributed according to their observed distribution. See also: [perplexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perplexity) (for measuring performance of sequence prediction).

You can easily compute log-likelihood per transition for both train and validation data.

For a general reference, I recommend:

- LR Rabiner, [A tutorial on hidden Markov models and selected applications in speech recognition](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk:5000/~vgg/rg/papers/hmm.pdf), Proceedings of the IEEE, 1989

Measuring uncertainty of this model can be more complicated and depend on the assumptions (as always). Below I mention two general approaches, which can be tailored for Markov model.

#### Approach 1: Gaussian approximation of likelihood

You need to be careful with the [stochastic matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix) conditions when differentiating log-likelihood.

See: MacKay's [Information Theory, Inference, and Learning Algorithms](http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/itprnn/book.pdf) Chapter IV Probabilities and Inference: Laplace's Method

#### Approach 2: Bayesian model (with matrix elements being random variables)

Depends on prior (I would go with a flat prior for stochastic matrix), and takes a lot of computational power (Markov Chain Monte Carlo, not to be confused with Markov Chain you are using), but gives interpretable results (and no risk of zero estimates).

Again, MacKay is wonderful at explaining this approach. For the technical part I recommend [PyMC3](https://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc3/) in Python, especially with this tutorial:

- [github.com/markdregan/Bayesian-Modelling-in-Python](https://github.com/markdregan/Bayesian-Modelling-in-Python)

I guess there are some tools in R, but I've never used them.

Comment: thanks a lot for your thorough answer and interesting resources! I'll start with computing log-likelihoods for train and test datasets and then move onto Bayesian model, I think. cheers!